# PHP script, that's called from AJAX, return value doesn't show up all the time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sockets

Here is the premise of what I'm doing:

> I have a program running in the background, a socket server, at all times.
>
> I created a website that calls a php script (using AJAX) that opens a client side socket, connects to the server, sends the request and receives it, then echos it out.
>
> This echo is the response is the 'return value' for my AJAX script.

This is this issue:

When I click a button, the information sends but, sometimes, the information never makes it back to the site.

- I know the request is being processed through the server because I can see the request running to completion on the server side.
- I know that the information from the server side is sending to the client (the website) because I have a code that checks if data was successfully sent from the server side.
- Sometimes the request is sent through and the appropriate response client side (an alert pop-up with information from the server) comes through.

**Website Code:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="weather" value="weather" />
<input type="submit" class="button" name="time" value="time" />
<input type="submit" class="button" name="date" value="date" />
</form>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
$('.button').click(function(){
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var ajaxurl = 'php/portserverclient.php',
    dataSend =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
    
    $.post(ajaxurl, dataSend, function (response) {
        // Response div goes here.
        //$('#servermessage').val($('#servermessage').val()+response); 
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

// -------------------------------------
// ----- Get Information Sent from Site
// -------------------------------------

if (isset($_POST['action']))
    {
         switch ($_POST['action']) {
            case 'weather':
                $in = "3";
                $request = "Weather";
                break;
            case 'time':
                $in = "2";
                $request = "Time";
                break;
            case 'date':
                $in = "1";
                $request = "Date";
        }
    }
else
{
    $in = "3";
    $request = "Weather";
}

// -------------------------------------
// ----- Open Client Side Socket
// -------------------------------------    

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$A1 = "Starting TCP/IP Connection... \n";

/* Get the port for the WWW service. */
$service_port = 51713;

/* Get the IP address for the target host. */
$address = '192.168.8.129';

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if ($socket === false) 
{
    $A2 = "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    exit;
} 
else {
    $A2 = "Socket Created...OK.\n";
}
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 5, 'usec' => 0));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 5, 'usec' => 0));

$A3 = "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) 
{
    $A4 = "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
    exit;
} 
else 
{
    $A4 = "OK.\n";
}

// -------------------------------------
// ----- Send message through socket
// -------------------------------------

$A5 = "Sending $request request...";
$sent = socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
$A6 = "OK.\n";

// -------------------------------------
// ----- Receive response through socket
// -------------------------------------

$out = ' ';
do{$out = socket_read($socket, 20, PHP_NORMAL_READ) ;}
while($out === false);

// -------------------------------------
// ----- Close Client Side Socket
// -------------------------------------

$A7 = "Closing socket...";
$A8 = "OK.\n";
echo "\n From PHP END: ", $A1,$A2,$A3,$A4,$A5,$A6,$A7,$A8,"Message: ", $out,"\n";

socket_shutdown($socket,2);
socket_close($socket);

exit;
?>
```

**C++ Server Side Code:**

```
//---- read buffer ---
    sizeofread = read(newsockfd, msg, 20);
    if (sizeofread <= 0 || msg[0] == 0x0A || msg[0] == 0x0D || msg[0] == 0x00) 
    {
        // Stops any buggy send (size of read <= 0)
        // Stops terminal from sending new line (0x0A & 0x0D) after each press enter
        // Stops terminal from sending 0 constantly (0x00)
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Received from TCP: %s \n",msg);
         
        //--- Send to Arduino ---
        printf( "Sending to Arduino: %s \n", msg);
        write( uartt, msg, 20 );
        delay(50);  // Here to account for how long it takes to send & receive 20 bytes at 9600 Baud

        //--- Receive from Arduino ---
        while (counter <= 2 && found == false)
        {
            if ( !( msgLength = serialDataAvail(uartt) ))
            {
                printf("Nothing to read \n");
                delay(1071); // Here to account for how long it takes to receive 1024 bytes at 9600 Baud
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                found = true;
                read(uartt, msg, msgLength);
                msg[msgLength] = 0;
                if (write(newsockfd, msg, 20) < 0)
                {
                    printf("Failed to send to socket \n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Succesfully sent to socket \n");
                }
                printf("From the Arduino: ");
                printf("%s \n", msg);
            }
            delay(100);
            serialFlush(uartt);
        }
        counter = 0;
        found = false;
        close(newsockfd);
        goto repeat;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is most likely that you're socket is still waiting on the response, or is still trying to connect. Resulting in the request to not end.

Comment: Here's the thing though. I know it connected to the server side because I watch the server side go through all the notions. This means, based on those two option, leaves it to it waiting on the response. Which I agree with. But, I have a code in the PHP (dumb I know, but I had to see if it'd work) that would wait until it received something. `do{ $out = socket_recv($socket, $msg, 20, MSG_DONTWAIT); } while($out <= 0);` So I don't think it can be that. I'll try and add a sleep delay just to see if it ends up working. And go on from there. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it might be possible that socket_recv is waiting until it's buffer is full.
What does the socket connect to? What should it receive? how do you end the message the socket should receive?

Comment: The socket connects to the server socket port and sends a "1", "2" or "3" with php code `socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));` It does this successfully because I'm watching it go through the terminal. To send the message back, I use `write(newsockfd, msg, 20);` (which is in C++). Where `newsockfd` is the websites socket and `msg` contains a string.

Comment: I ran the PHP code by itself and it receives the msg fine every time. Which means theres something wrong with my jQuery code. It's not running the callback function for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this riddle was that I needed to disable the Submit buttons default event. Normally, in HTML, the submit button refreshes the page, this must be stopped.

It was stopped like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(event){ 
    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var ajaxurl = 'php/portserverclient.php',
    dataSend =  {'action': clickBtnValue};

    $.post(ajaxurl, dataSend, function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks guys